# Gmod | Entity Spawning

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

```
if SERVER then
        function SWEP:PrimaryAttack()
            if self.Owner:GetEyeTrace().HitPos:Distance(self.Owner:GetPos()) < 100 then
                local entity = ents.Create( "gred_emp_grw34" )
                if ( !IsValid( entity ) ) then return end 
                entity:SetPos( self.Owner:GetEyeTrace().HitPos )
                local entang = self.Owner:GetAngles()
                entity:SetAngles(Angle(0, entang.y, 0) +Angle(0, 180, 0))
                entity:SetModel("models/props_artillery/german/r_mortar_gw34.mdl" )
                entity:Spawn()
                self.Owner:StripWeapon( "turret_entplace" )
            end
        end
    
        function SWEP:SecondaryAttack() end
    end
```

This is my Code for spawning an entitiy with a Weapon now the problem is the Entity spawns in the floor so i am trying to add some Height to it can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

The entity's position is `self.Owner:GetEyeTrace().HitPos` and because you are likely looking at the floor the entity spawn in the floor. [I think you have something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4BSQ.png).

What you need to do is offsetting the position. It can be done like this :

```lua
local z_offset = 5 -- the offset you need (depends on the entity)

hitPos = self.Owner:GetEyeTrace().HitPos -- the position of the eye's hitting point
spawnPos = hitPos:Add(Vector(0, 0, z_offset) -- offset the pos

entity:SetPos( spawnPos )
```

Concerning the offset, i can't find anything (on the gmod wiki) to determine it... I think you will need to try different offset... Also, if you have other entities to spawn, you may also need to make a table with the different offsets.